# Hint on how extract a text from a List<string>

Tags: java, regex, string

In my java application I have a `List<String> sbuff_Test = new ArrayList<>();` structure that I fill during the execution. When the `sbuff_Test` is ready, I put every string of it in a `jTextArea`. My output is something like that:

```
Please choose Node: 
2 :  Low   s23_t0
1 :  High  s23_t0           (Id = 0)

* TESTPAD  MAIN  MENU   (v10r0p0) *
----------------------------------

LowPT  PAD  s23_t0  on node 2

1 = Initialize PAD
2 = PRODE MENU
3 = TTC   MENU
4 = CM    MENU
5 = FPGA  MENU
6 = LINK  MENU
7 = CAN   MENU
8 = ELMB  MENU
9 = SPLITTER MENU
10 = Change CURRENT PAD
11 = Reset full PAD
12 = Warm Initialize PAD
13 = Change Pad configuration
14 = Change CM latencies  
15 = Phase measurement
16 = Power ON/OFF
17 = Print PAD Status
18 = Measurement loop
19 = Read CM trigger frequencies
20 = fast check of locks
21 = TRIGGER MENU
22 = Read CM BC ids
23 = Test CM BC ids with prode
24 = Test CM BC ids with TTC
25 = Test init low-high
 0 = Quit
TESTPAD:  ELMB MENU
(1) ELMB reset 
(2) power OFF/ON ELMB on Node 1
(3) ELMB firm/hard version 
(4) set CAN-debug ON/OFF
(5) set the communication rate
(6) download XPG file into FLASH for localInit
(0) exit 
 2
 Firmware Version SV22
 Hardware Version pad8
 TESTPAD:  ELMB MENU
 (1) ELMB reset 
 (2) power OFF/ON ELMB on Node 1
 (3) ELMB firm/hard version 
 (4) set CAN-debug ON/OFF
 (5) set the communication rate
 (6) download XPG file into FLASH for localInit
 (0) exit
```

Now, I want an hint on how extract only the text that I need; for example, for the text above:

```
LowPT  PAD  s23_t0  on node 2
Firmware Version SV22
Hardware Version pad8
```

The trouble is that the part of text that I must delete is variable and I can't find an approach for this problem. What do you suggest for a similar problem? Thanks for the hint.

Comment: Do you always want to extract `LowPT`, `Firmware Version` and `Hardware Version`?

Comment: With the indexOf() method of the string you can search for substrings

Comment: Yes, always. This is only a part of the output that generally the program gives to me. Generally, I must always delete the part of the output that begin with "MENU" and ends with "0 - exit" or "(0) exit" etc.

Comment: indexOf() method can be used. But best practice is that, you have to be sure for the index.  Key,Value pair can be used

Comment: Can you go in debug and show us what really is stored in your List of strings ? I think it is kind a hard to understand what exactly happens here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT:**

To delete the unwanted phrase you just need to use `matcher.replaceAll("")` method, In this Example I will use the old patterns:

```
String text = jTextAreaName.getText();

//This is the list of the wanted groups
String[] patterns = new String[]{"(LowPT .+)[\\r\\n]", "(Firmware Version .+)[\\r\\n]", "(Hardware Version .+)[\\r\\n]"};


//Then delete the three matched groups like this
for(int i=0; i<patterns.length; i++) {
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(patterns[i]);
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(text);
    while(matcher.find()) {
       text = matcher.replaceAll("");
    }
}
```

Here's the **[Updated DEMO](https://ideone.com/B78hrn)**.

---

In that case you need to use a ***[Regex Matcher](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html)*** and **matching groups** to  only extract the wanted parts from it:

```
String text = jTextAreaName.getText();

//This is the list of the wanted groups
String[] patterns = new String[]{"(LowPT .+)[\\r\\n]", "(Firmware Version .+)[\\r\\n]", "(Hardware Version .+)[\\r\\n]"};


//Then extract the three matched groups like this
String myResult="";
for(int i=0; i<patterns.length; i++) {
     //compile each matching group and find matches.
     Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(patterns[i]);
     Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(text);
     while(matcher.find()) {
         myResult += matcher.group(1);
         myResult += "\n";
     }
}
```

This a **[Live DEMO](https://ideone.com/qaI44J)** where you can test it, giving the following result:

> LowPT  PAD  s23_t0  on node 2
>
> Firmware Version SV22
>
> Hardware Version pad8

**Explanation:**

- `(LowPT .+)[\\r\\n]` is a matching group for the line *`LowPT  PAD  s23_t0  on node 2`*.
- `(Firmware Version .+)[\\r\\n]` is a matching group for the line *`Firmware Version SV22`*.
- `(Hardware Version .+)[\\r\\n]` is a matching group for the line *`Hardware Version pad8`*.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. This however is good only for search the three rows of example but this lines can change. Is it possible adapt your answer conversely, namely put in the patterns the phrases to delete (since that these don't change)?

Comment: Yes of course you can change it, to fit the unwanted results, I will EDIT my answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you only need LowPT,Firmware and Hardware Version ,read your file line by line.
If your line contains one of the above keywords print the current line and continue to the next one.

Comment: No, unfortunately that of above is only an example.